# Use the "bare" param option in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am setting a post request.  However, I noticed that instead of getting back plain data i am getting back an entire webpage with default layout and corresponding view?

What I want to know is how to set the CakeResponse "params" default options.  Specifically the 'bare' one so that whenever I do a post it just returns data, not a view / layout.

Thanks

Comment: How are you sending the post request? From a form? Did you use the FormHelper? Usually to get form post you'd use `$this->request->data['model_here']`. Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I am using FormHelper.  

What i noticed is that even though it is a post, CakePHP still sets the views / layouts.  Now I know you never should, but if I inspected that post in a browser it shows up as a webpage.  Which, I think is just awful.  

So I noticed CakePHP has a 'bare' options that you SOMEHOW can pass into the Cake Request options. This is what i am wondering how i would set because I can't find it anywehere int he documentation.

Comment: Could you post an example of what the post returns? `$this->request->data['model_here']` should return an array of your form data.

Comment: see that part is fine Tim.

What i have an issue is that behind the scenes CAKE is still assigning a view and a layout... etc.

Comment: I don't know if what I am saying is making sense.  Basically what it comes down to is that I would like to know how to set the CakeResponse -params 'bare' option before making a request.

Comment: It outputs a response like this:  

array(5) {
  ["_method"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    blah-blah-: i am data
  }
}

--------------
<html>
IAM A WEB PAGE< SPECIFICALLY A VIEW / LAYOUT, WHY THE HECK AM I BEING CALLED ON A POST???
</html>

Make sense ???

Comment: Seriously???  Nobody figured out how to use the "bare" option for CakePHP yet??

Comment: BOOM!!  Had given up on this and just ran across the answer.  Going to write it below and close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->autoRender = false;

You do not need a view folder, file or anything.  Great for just responding with plain json / text / etc.